# How to use *some* functions of CRT with CRT Disabled?

Tags: c++, crt

I have disabled CRT, however I wish to use some of the run-time functions like strtok, strcmpy, strcpy and so on but I do not want the entire CRT running could someone tell me how I can use those functions without running CRT and enabling all CRT function.

I only want few CRT functions, could someone assist me?

Kind Regards,

Rohan Vijjhalwar

Comment: What do you mean by "disable CRT"?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What?  Hack out the bits you don't want to run.  Comment it, or whatever, then rebuild the crt.

Comment: Actually, this is a very unclear question and I'm going to VTC as such.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I am trying to cut down on the size of a project I am working on, its not the point and disabling CRT means I am not using the CRT, in other words I am not using mainCRTStartup() which usually runs

Comment: @MartinJames No, its not the point its how can I only load the functions I want - nothing more. Its to cut down on size of the file. It is important for me.

Comment: @RohanVijjhalwar To you it may not be, but to others it is.

Comment: Again, what?  crt size is usually insignificant anyway.

Comment: @MartinJames I know it sounds crazy, but I am trying to cut down on every size. Its not a actual project - I am just trying to research and doing a challenge to get a certain code to smallest as possible. :D

Comment: @RohanVijjhalwar Your question is pretty much *How can I use the functions of a library without initializing it?*.

Comment: I suggest to change the title of the question. You don't ask for initialization but for use of the function. This might confuse some others w/o embedded in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a kind of C run-time library, as you already told us with the wish for strcmp & Co. If you think you would get any benefit in creating smaller binaries or less dependencies to DLLs you can use any tiny-CRT.

For the use in a boot loader I wrote my own library with just the functions I needed. E.g. you can code the function `strcpy` as:

```
// choose const for arguments where necessary.
char* strcpy(char *dst, char *src)
{
    char* dest = dst;

    // copy char by char until '\0' is found.
    while ( *dest++ = *src++ )
    {
    }

    return dst;
}
```

If you have a function like `strtok` that isn't stateless, you have to initialize the state. So you will have to initialize your tiny CRT.

If you fear you can't write it entirely by your own search for someone else who did it for you, e.g. at [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15156/Tiny-C-Runtime-Library) or [µCLib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UClibc)